# weird glitch i am unable to hiden element with id ="11" but i am able to hide element with id other than 11

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a JavaScript like this:

```
for (loop with id from 0 to 19) {  //ignore formating understand logic please
  var liId = i; //(ofloop)

  document.getElementById(liId).style.visibility = "hidden";
  or
  document.getElementById(tickelementid).style.display = "none";
}
```

explanation: element img has id 0 to 19; (so I have total 20 img btn).
When loop runs all the img gets hidden except img with `id='11'` which doesn't hide.

Even if I try to hide element with `id="11"` it doesn't work. It only works if I manually hide via CSS.

```
if (result.message == "ok.") {
  alert(liId); // liId loops from 0 to 19
  document.getElementById(tickelementid).style.display = "inline-block"; // this works
  document.getElementById(liId).style.visibility = "hidden"; // this works for all but not for liId="11"
  document.getElementById(liId).style.display = "none"; // this works for all but not for liId="11"
} else {
  document.getElementById(liId).style.display = "inline-block";
  document.getElementById(tickelementid).style.display = "none";
}
```

no error at all

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] to your question? It will be hard, if not impossible for us to answer your question if we cannot reproduce it.

Comment: I can only guess there is another element with id 11

Comment: @frz3993 it targets just the first one in that case: https://jsfiddle.net/tk5sdcx6/. so either something, somewhere is getting hidden or nothing is getting hidden because `id="11"` doesn't exist.

Comment: @frz3993 you are right. i had 2 elements with id = "11" as everything was dynamic i couldnt understand.. i replaced my numbers with somehing like "row-" . $i and now its working fine..  Thank you all for the try... really appreciated